# Java swing table customize checkbox column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I used TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor add a checkBox table column.
the code as followed:

```
class PanelCellEditorRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements
        TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        checkBox.setSelected((boolean)value);
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
        //table.addRowSelectionInterval(row,row);
       /* if(val)
            table.addRowSelectionInterval(row,row);
        else
            table.removeRowSelectionInterval(row,row);*/
        System.out.println("row::"+row+" column::"+column+" isSelected::"+value);
        return checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        checkBox.setSelected((boolean)value);
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
      /*  if(!isSelected)
            table.addRowSelectionInterval(row,row);
        else
            table.removeRowSelectionInterval(row,row);*/
        table.getValueAt(row,column);
        return checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return checkBox.isSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want the corresponding row in the table to be selected when the checkbox is selected. When the CheckBox is unchecked, the corresponding row in the table is also unchecked. When the mouse clicks on another row, the selected rows state does not change. Could it be achieved by rewriting the cellrenderer and cellEditor method?

Comment: Should work with adding a `SelectionListener` to the checkbox and overwriting the default selectionListener for the JTable

Comment: when I add "selectionListener" to checkbox, it will become an infinite loop.

Comment: There is no need for a custom renderer/editor. The JTable already provided a renderer/editor for a check box. The column should contain Boolean values and you override the getColumnClass(...) method to return Boolean.class so the table can use the proper renderer/editor. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: In your way, I can't achieve the effects I mentioned above and the checkbox grid background will be blue when the corresponding row is selected(I want the background always be white).

Comment: do you know how overwriting the default selectionListener for the table? could you give me a example, thanks in advance.